# Resharper and roslyn analzyers in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, roslyn

To maximise resharper performance in large visual studio projects should we be removing all roslyn analyzers?

Eg in this screenshot you can see the "MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset" Does unticking these improve performance?

[image]

Does leaving these ticked double up on reported errors. Eg does resharper effectively replace all of these analyzers/rules with it's own?

I don't understand where the roslyn analyzer and the reshaper analyser overlap and how to maximise performance.

Could someone answer the two questions. Firstly where do the two systems overlap (if they do at all).  Secondly can I disable all the roslyn ones and will this improve performance?

Answer (score 0):

1. Do they overlap: Most definitely, though its honestly a complex answer and the functionality between the two is not identical.
2. Can I disable all roslyn analysis: not entirely however, under Tools -> Options you can disable full solution analysis
   [image]

Comment: I already have full solution analysis disabled but the live analysis still runs. How can I stop the live analysis from executing?

Comment: > How can I stop the live analysis from executing?

you cannot, many of the IDE features (XAML, ASP.NET etc.) require analysis to run and cannot be switched off

Comment: I would also look at this guide: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Performance-considerations-for-large-solutions